# UITableCell clipToBounds property odd behavior

Tags: ios

I have a custom UITableCell that has labels and a UIView.

Lets say the tablecell is set at a height of 50px and 10 labels are placed with 10px seperation. With `cell.clipToBounds = YES`, we only see 5 of the labels which is nice and expected.

The custom UIView on this custom table cell is say 200px in height. I ASSUMED the UIView would get clipped as the labels did because the UIView is added as a subview to the cell itself which clips everything else just fine but the UIVIew doesnt get clipped at all. The entire UIView (200px height) is shown.

pseudo code:

```
cellForRowAtIndexPath... ... {

...

...

CustomCell * cell = ... ...

cell.clipToBounds = YES;

cell.customView.hidden = NO;

[self.view addSubView:cell.customView];

[self.view bringSubviewToFront:cell.customView];

}
```

In storyboard i literally create a custom cell and add 10 labels as mentioned above and drag and drop a UIView in the cell with a large height.

So why don't views added to "content view" of `UITableViewCell` get clipped?

Comment: have you checked the autoLayout/auto resize ?

Comment: Ive tried with autoLayout and without and its the same result

Comment: check the auto resize.

Answer (score 0):

also set cell viewContent clipsToBound

```
cell.contentview.clipToBounds = YES;
```

and also check if the cells are overlapping, then make sure you are passing the right height in heightForRowAtIndexPath method of tableview.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   return 50;
}
```

Comment: Ive tried setting "cell.contentview.clipToBounds = YES;" and just for kicks even "cell.customView.clipTobounds = YES;" and its STILL not clipping =(. The cells are not overlapping either. Only the custom UIView overlaps everything!